How to have an asyncio StreamReader and StreamWriter that work on a buffer?
For writing unit tests for IO code in the past I've used BytesIO instead of a real file/socket/etc. so I can test my functions on hand crafted data. As far as I can tell Python provides no async equivalent; I realize there's no real IO to do for a buffer, but you need classes that obey the same interface in order for your test code manipulating a buffer to Just Work with the same production code that normally uses files/sockets.
I tried writing a subclass like class AsyncBytesIO(asyncio.StreamReader, asyncio.StreamWriter) but at runtime it crashes whenever an exception occurs because asyncio assumes there is a _transport member on my subclass, which is mentioned nowhere in the docs which makes me skeptical these are intended to be subclassed. But it also seems like the only common interface for doing asynchronous streaming reading/writing. How is this supposed to be done?
Reproducer:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio
from io import BytesIO

class AsyncBytesIO(asyncio.StreamReader, asyncio.StreamWriter):
    def __init__(self, data: bytes = b""):
        self._buffer = BytesIO(data)
        self._closed = False

    async def read(self, n: int = -1) -> bytes:
        return self._buffer.read(n)

    async def readline(self) -> bytes:
        return self._buffer.readline()

    async def readexactly(self, n: int) -> bytes:
        return self._buffer.read(n)

    def at_eof(self) -> bool:
        return self._buffer.tell() == len(self._buffer.getvalue())

    def write(self, data: bytes) -> None:
        if self._closed:
            raise ValueError("Write operation on a closed stream")
        self._buffer.write(data)

    async def drain(self) -> None:
        pass

    def close(self) -> None:
        self._closed = True

    def is_closing(self) -> bool:
        return self._closed

    def getvalue(self) -> bytes:
        return self._buffer.getvalue()

    def seek(self, pos: int) -> None:
        self._buffer.seek(pos)

    def tell(self) -> int:
        return self._buffer.tell()

    def reset(self) -> None:
        self._buffer.seek(0)

async def test():
    x = AsyncBytesIO()
    assert False

asyncio.run(test())

Results in:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/async_test.py", line 53, in <module>
    asyncio.run(test())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/base_events.py", line 687, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/tmp/async_test.py", line 51, in test
    assert False
           ^^^^^
AssertionError
Exception ignored in: <function StreamWriter.__del__ at 0x77061961ed40>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/asyncio/streams.py", line 411, in __del__
AttributeError: 'AsyncBytesIO' object has no attribute '_transport'


It would appear that asyncio is trying to clean up the transport mechanism in the event of an Exception, which is a perfectly reasonable thing for it to do.  Why don't you add a __del__ method to your class, to hide the inherited __del__ method?

@PaulCornelius I could but at this point I'm not sure if I'm supposed to be extending the class at all?

I don't think there are Python police who are going to come down on your head because you aren't "supposed" to subclass the Stream classes, and anyway I don't know why you think you are not supposed to.  The error you are getting makes a reference to a "private" variable, which you wouldn't expect to be documented.  I don't see why you subclassed those classes in the first place - I think you don't use any superclass methods.  You could simply rewrite the class definition to eliminate the inheritance (class AsyncBytesIO:), and then the default (empty) __del__ method would be used.

@PaulCornelius less worried about python police, more worried about my subclass breaking in a future python version ;) I need the inheritance because I'm using mypy, otherwise existing functions that take asyncio.StreamReader or asyncio.StreamWriter won't accept my type

I'll try again.  "asyncio assumes there is a _transport member on my subclass."  I think that statement is incorrect.  The Exception occurs in the StreamWriter.__del__ method, which is very likely called by the Python environment (not asyncio) during the garbage collection process.  Since your class inherits from StreamWriter and you did not override __del__, Python of course calls the inherited __del__ method.  That's standard.  Since your class does not require any cleanup, just declare a dummy __del__ method and the exception should go away.
